# C# 4.0 - Threads on an Interval

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using C# 4.0. I have a block of code I would like to execute every 2-3 minutes. What is the correct way to do this with the 4.0 threading features available?

Comment: There is no single 'correct' way, and not even a 'best' way without a lot more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use System.Threading.Timer.

```
new Timer(TimerTick,null,TimeSpan.Zero,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

private void TimerTick(object obj)
{
    Thread myThread =  new Thread(() => {});
    myThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: If you anchor it in a (static) var you have the chance of stopping/changing it, and you avoid all the GC discussions.

Comment: @Henk Sure but I think a stripped example is better, or?

Comment: Usually but not in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx). One thing to keep in mind is that it will go off disregarding of what your code is doing (reentrance). In other words if the desired interval is 3 minutes and the code that you execute takes 2 minutes it will fire 1 minute after this code it is done. Furthermore if you code takes more than 3 minutes then it will be called in parallel and you will have to take care of thread safety. If this is ok and you don't expect your code to take long time then you can use following:

```
Timer _timer = new Timer(DoWork, "someArg", TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

private void DoWork(object state) {
   // this code will get executed every 3 seconds:
   String argument = (String) state;
}
```

But if you want your timer to be sequential (wait for the code to complete before starting new interval) you will need to reset it on every Tick.

```
Timer _timer = new Timer(DoWork, "someArg", TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

private void DoWork(object state) {
    // this code will get executed 3 seconds after the last DoWork finished
    String argument = (String)state;


    // make sure that timer will get executed in 3 seconds but will not repeat.
    // this code guarantees that timer will wait for this code to complete 
    // before starting new interval.
    _timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
}
```

You also need to make sure that your timer instance will not get garbage collected while you still need it. Also note that .NET contains 3 different timer classes but you will most likely need **System.Threading.Timer** not **System.Windows.Forms.Timer** and not **System.Timers.Timer**. Good summary is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

If you foresee more advanced scheduling requirements (run code every other Monday etc) then you can use [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). It is an open source enterprise job scheduler that has a lot of other features and is relatively simple to integrate with (reference one dll).

Comment: How would one make sure the timer does not get garbage collected ? That would add a lot of value to your answer here - I am still plugging you one for a more complete answer, but it would be nice to have the code to protect against GC.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a utility class for infinite thread processing a while ago. Here it goes....

```
public interface IProcessorThread
    {
        void Start();

        void Stop();
    }

    public abstract class BaseProcessorThread : IProcessorThread
    {
        protected Boolean IsRunning;
        protected readonly Thread ServiceThread;
        protected readonly Int32 PollingFrequencySeconds;

        #region Constructors

        protected BaseProcessorThread(Int32 pollingFrequencySeconds)
        {
            this.PollingFrequencySeconds = pollingFrequencySeconds;
            ServiceThread = new Thread(Process);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Protected Methods

        protected abstract void Process();

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        public void Start()
        {
            IsRunning = true;
            ServiceThread.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            IsRunning = false;
            ServiceThread.Join(2000);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class LifetimeInfiniteThread : BaseProcessorThread
    {
        #region Fields

        private readonly Action actionMethod;
        private readonly Action<Exception> exceptionMethod;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public LifetimeInfiniteThread(Int32 pollingFrequencySeconds, Action actionMethod, Action<Exception> exceptionMethod)
            : base(pollingFrequencySeconds)
        {
            this.actionMethod = actionMethod;
            this.exceptionMethod = exceptionMethod;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Protected Methods

        protected override void Process()
        {
            while (IsRunning)
            {
                try
                {
                    actionMethod.Invoke();
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    exceptionMethod.Invoke(ex);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(PollingFrequencySeconds * 1000);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Using 60 for 1 minute.
        var thread = new LifetimeInfiniteThread(60, Run, HandleException);

        thread.Start();
        Console.Read();
        thread.Stop();
    }


    static void Run()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("I m running..");
    }

    static void HandleException(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way is to use [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609)

```
var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
timer.Subscribe(tick => { //execute me });
```

The code being executed will be handled by a threadpool worker thread, so you need to make sure you have the correct safety guards in place if it accesses shared state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Threading.Timer` class for it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Solution using a timer:

```
public class Worker : IDisposable
{
    private readonly System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    private readonly int PeriodInMs = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2).TotalMilliseconds;

    public Worker()
    {
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_ => OnTick(), null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _timer.Change(0, PeriodInMs);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void OnTick()
    {
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        try
        {
            //Your work goes here
        }
        finally
        {
            _timer.Change(PeriodInMs, PeriodInMs);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```