# What should be the approach for writing polling service in c# for devices with varying interval

Tags: c#, multithreading, modbus, plc

I have close to 400 PLC devices with Modbus interface which I want to poll and store the result in MySQL database.  User will configure the polling interval for each device, say Temperature polling at 500 ms, Triangular waves at 1000 ms, Environmental parameters at 5000 ms, etc.  I have stored all these information in database.

Now I want to write a windows service, which will do following:

1. Read the communication parameters for each device from the database, e.g., IP address, register address, register count, etc.
2. Initiate a thread for each device with specific interval
3. That thread will keep polling the device and write the value in database, until the service is stopped.

Now, my question is how to implement separate thread for each device with its specific interval.

I'm using C# with nModbus library.

Comment: I think this question would benefit from emphasizing the fairly limited scope of what you need: threading with poll-interval-per-device settings. Can you [edit] accordingly? Otherwise it sounds almost like you're asking for a substantial coding project.

Comment: Multiple threads for 400 devices? Hope you have one hell of a computer.

Comment: Personally, instead of initiating a thread for each device, I would initiate a few base-threads, that handle a group of devices each. (You could easily write it to initiate four threads, handling 100 of the PLC's each.) Each thread can be on a 10ms timeout, thus giving you the very-fine granularity you would require.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I think this title looks more descriptive.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Yes Ron.  I have a server setup for this. :)

Comment: @EBrown: Nice solution.  Would try this and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of resources on how to poll on an interval. [C# 4.0 - Threads on an Interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966605/c-sharp-4-0-threads-on-an-interval)  You could enumerate over a collection of configured timer intervals and spin of a thread for each.

With that many concurrent threads I would suggest queuing these.  Whether you use a queue product such as MSMQ or custom roll some sort of thread safe concurrent dictionary to handling the queuing. Here's one resource on custom queuing: http://www.nullskull.com/a/1464/producerconsumer-queue-and-blockingcollection-in-c-40.aspx

Hopefully, this will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! This is promising, but I need to do a lot of research.  Will update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple System.Timers.Timer class;
Here is the sample code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Timer interval in ms
        // in your case read from database
        double timerIntervalInMs = 1000.00;
        var myTimer = new Timer(timerIntervalInMs);
        // I generally prefer to use AutoReset false 
        // and explicitly start the timer within the elapsed event.
        // Thus you can ensure that there will not be overlapping elapsed events.
        myTimer.AutoReset = false;
        myTimer.Elapsed += OnMyTimedEvent;
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
        myTimer.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static void OnMyTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("On timer event");
        // Do work
        var timerObj = (Timer) source;
        timerObj.Start();
    }

}
```

Comment: This will create only one timer for one task.  I need to poll many devices in separate timers, which will keep polling at specified interval. Will try to get this done by implementing multiple timers, and update.